# new react app is not created after running create-react-app in cmd

Tags: reactjs

[after running the create-react-app command, the progress stopped right there as shown in screenshot. Node version 12.13.1 npm 6.12.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwRWD.png)

Comment: Please provide code that is generating errors instead of posting links.

Answer (score 1):

Create-react-app is not recommended to install globally after version 3.3.0
Fix it by removing with npm uninstall -g create-react-app

Then run it with: npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: Not only is it not recommended but it straight up won't work in my experience.

Comment: Hi, did what you suggested, first i uninstalled create-react-app globally then npx create-react-app. still facing the same issue.

Comment: also i deleted npm-cache folder before creating the app